# Introducir varios datos en una misma linea C++

Tags: c++

Hola me gustaria resolver este problema de la siguiente forma de manera que pueda introducir todos los datos necesarios en la misma linea y con espacios.

```
int personas = 0, velocidades = 0;

cout << "Introduce la cantidad de personas y las velocidades de cada uno: ";
cin >> personas >> velocidades;

(este código obviamente no funciona, asigna siempre el primer valor para segunda variable)
```

Ejemplo de la entrada que quiero: 
5 10 40 20 11 16

Salida (utilizaría un algoritmo para averiguar el mayor):
40

Comment: ¿ Porqué dices que no funciona ? `cin >> a >> b;` funciona perfecto, mientras separes los números con espacios O_o

Comment: Bueno al parecer lo que @GuillermoSantamaria quiere hacer es que si él pone por ejemplo `2` en **cantidad de personas** entonces poder agregar **2 
 velocidades** posteriormente teniendo como entrada 3 parámetros, y obviamente en el código que muestra no soportará eso ya que solo tiene 2 parámetros de entrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la solucion que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

Dejo comentadas las lineas importantes para que comprendas lo que hice

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class Container>
void split(const std::string& str, Container& cont)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(cont));
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string stringIng; // Cadena ingresada
    cout << "Introduce la cantidad de personas y las velocidades de cada uno: ";
    getline(cin, stringIng); // Con esto se pide el ingreso de los datos pero como string

    std::vector<std::string> arrPartido; // Declaramos el array de datos que ingresarán
    split(stringIng, arrPartido); // partimos la cadena ingresada que contiene los datos de personas y velocidades

    int personas = atoi(arrPartido[0].c_str()); // La primera posición se asume que será el número de personas
    int velocidades[personas - 1]; // Declaramos las velocidades

    for(int i = 0; i < personas; i += 1) { // Convertimos y llenamos el array de velocidades
        velocidades[i] = atoi(arrPartido[i + 1].c_str());
    }


    // Muestro los valores obtenidos
    cout << "Personas: "<< personas << endl;
    cout << "Velocidades" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < personas; i += 1) {
        cout << velocidades[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Con el array `velocidades` es con la que tendrias que trabajar para sacar el mayor y lo que necesites.

Ésta es la salida que obtuve:

[image: Consola]

Bueno no soy un experto en **C++** pero éste es el código con el que puedo colaborarte espero te sirva ;) Saludos.

Comment: `int velocidades[personas - 1];` es un VLA (**V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray). Esta característica no está soportada por el estándar. Si te funciona es porque tu compilador te hace ese favor, pero no es una solución portable y perfectamente puede dejar de compilarte en otros compiladores

Comment: Hola, gracias a todos por las respuestas. Pero como podría resolverlo usando la función getline y sin usar arrays?

Answer (score 1):

> Hola me gustaria resolver este problema de la siguiente forma de manera que pueda introducir todos los datos necesarios en la misma linea y con espacios.

El código que has puesto en tu pregunta es justo lo que necesitas. Me explico:

A la hora de leer con `cin` es indiferente leerlo todo del tirón:

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

O por partes:

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
```

Lo que hace el operador de extracción `>>` es descartar todos los separadores (generalmente espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea) e intentar convertir el dato que encuentre a continuación.

De hecho, fíjate que no es necesario decirle a `cin` cuándo se ha de encontrar con un salto de línea y otros casos similares.

El caso, dado que tu necesitas leer una cantidad de velocidades igual al valor del primer argumento, necesitas dividir la lectura en dos partes:

```
cout << "Introduce la cantidad de personas y las velocidades de cada uno: ";
cin >> personas;
std::vector<int> velocidad(personas);
for( int i=0; i<personas; i++ )
  std::cin >> velocidad[i];
```

Si los campos a leer fuesen siempre fijos, podrías simplificar la lectura tal y como la presentas en tu código:

```
int personas;
std::vector<int> velocidad(5);
std::cin >> personas >> velocidad[0] >> velocidad[1] >> velocidad[2] >> ...
```

> (este código obviamente no funciona, asigna siempre el primer valor para segunda variable)

Si sucede eso es porque tienes basura en el buffer de entrada o porque estás metiendo la pata en otro sitio. Como no has puesto el resto del código no te puedo dar más detalles.

> Ejemplo de la entrada que quiero

Una vez leídos los `personas` números, encontrar el mayor de ellos es trivial, basta con recorrer la lista de números y quedarse con el mayor de ellos:

**Comprobación explícita**

```
int mayor = 0;
for( int v : velocidades )
  if( v > mayor ) mayor = v;
```

**Usando la librería de algoritmos**

```
int mayor = 0;
for( int v : velocidades )
  mayor = std::max(v, mayor);
```

**Usando la librería de algoritmos V2**

```
int mayor = std::max_element(velocidades.begin(), velocidades.end());
```

Claro que también puedes ahorrarte el array:

```
std::cin >> personas;
int mayor = 0;
for( int i=0; i<personas; i++ )
{
  int velocidad;
  std::cin >> velocidad;
  mayor = std::max(mayor, velocidad);
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias a todos por las respuestas. Pero como podría resolverlo usando la función getline y sin usar arrays?

Comment: @GuillermoSantamaría ¿y por qué motivo ibas a querer leer con `getline`? No veo la necesidad de complicarse la vida si no está debidamente justificado

Comment: Es un ejercicio que necesito resolver explicitamente con ese tipo de entrada, de forma seguida y sin el uso de vectores. Podría resolverlo perfectamente introduciendo los datos uno a uno, pero no sé que función usar para leer los datos y compararlos.

Comment: @GuillermoSantamaría pues si ese es un requisito entonces, tal vez, debería haber estado especificado en la pregunta... no somos adivinos. Quizás deberías crear una nueva pregunta centrándote en ese aspecto en concreto. Ya tienes respuestas en esta pregunta y no sería justo adaptarlas a una necesidad que antes no existía